# php preg_match not giving a result?

Tags: php, regex

sorry, I'm not good at php, this might be a very obvious mistake. I'm trying to this:

```
  $datum = "Samstag, 26.10.2013";
  echo("<p>".$datum."</p>");

  $regresult = preg_match("(.*)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,4})",$datum, $matches);
  echo("<p>Result: ".$regresult."</p>");
  echo("<p>Error: ".preg_last_error()."</p>");
  echo("<p>Match: ".$matches[2]."</p>");
```

and the result is:

```
<p>Samstag, 26.10.2013</p><p>Result: </p><p>Error: 0</p><p>Match: </p>
```

but in the documentation of preg_match it says:

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it
>   does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I get a warning that says "preg_match(): Unknown modifier '('". Have you suppressed those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing your [delimeters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

preg_match requires you to do something like this

```
preg_match('/{pattern}/', $subject);
```

In this case I've used `/` as my delimeter.

An example: match exactly 3 digits

```
preg_match('/\d{3}/', $subject);
```

[If you check out php's documentation on preg_match you can see other examples](https://www.php.net/preg_match)

edit:

Php native date time functions reference links:

**[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)**

**[date/time formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)**

**[date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)**

**[time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)**

Comment: thanks that works. still: no output from preg_last_error() is against the documentation :-(

Comment: @DirkHaase you might find the native php date and time conversion functions helpful (they return false when they are passed bad datetime data and can be used to take pretty much every date/time format you want and convert or check them, just make sure you only pass them the part of the string that comprises the date/time). I'll update my answer with reference links.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use delimeters `/` in regex pattern:

```
preg_match("/(.*)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,4})/", $datum, $matches);
            ↑                                        ↑
        delimeter                                delimeter
```

See **[this demo](http://ideone.com/sJh4X5)** - it works...